# Shorter way in php laravel to load a model in another similar one?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to copy every property of the ***contract model*** into this another ***templatecontract model*** and so on. My code works, but I don't know much about laravel (or php in fact) and my intuition tells me that there must be a better way, or more elegant way.

`fill()` from Laravel does not get much better. Maybe with a constructor?

Equal tables:

> Contract -> TemplateContract
>
> Chapter -> TemplateChapter
>
> Clause -> TemplateClause

```
public function storeTemplate(ContractCreateRequest $request)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            $contract = Contract::find($request->input()['type']);
            $templatecontract = new TemplateContract();
            
            $templatecontract->id = $contract->id;
            $templatecontract->pid = $contract->pid;
            $templatecontract->deleted = $contract->deleted;
            $templatecontract->sorting = $contract->sorting;
            $templatecontract->created_at = $contract->created_at;
            $templatecontract->updated_at = $contract->updated_at;
            $templatecontract->deleted_at = $contract->deleted_at;
            $templatecontract->title = $contract->title;
            $templatecontract->description = $contract->description;
            $templatecontract->hidden = $contract->hidden;
            $templatecontract->contract_type = $contract->contract_type;
            $templatecontract->process_type = $contract->process_type;
            $templatecontract->tstamp = $contract->tstamp;
            $templatecontract->is_english = $contract->is_english;
            $templatecontract->usecasetitle = $contract->usecasetitle;
            
            if (Auth::user()) {
                $templatecontract->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            }
            if($templatecontract->save())
            {
                $chapter = DB::table('chapter')->where('contract', $templatecontract->id)->get();
                if(isset($chapter))
                {
                    foreach ($chapter as $key => $value) {
                        $templatechapter = new TemplateChapter();
                        $templatechapter->clause = $value->clause;
                        $templatechapter->contract = $value->contract;
                        $templatechapter->created_at = $value->created_at;
                        $templatechapter->deleted = $value->deleted;
                        $templatechapter->headlinetype = $value->headlinetype;
                        $templatechapter->hidden = $value->hidden;
                        $templatechapter->id = $value->id;
                        $templatechapter->must = $value->must;
                        $templatechapter->note = $value->note;
                        $templatechapter->sorting = $value->sorting;
                        $templatechapter->title = $value->title;
                        $templatechapter->tstamp = $value->tstamp;
                        $templatechapter->updated_at = $value->updated_at;
                        $templatechapters[] = $templatechapter;
                        if($templatechapter->save())
                        {
                            $clause = DB::table('clause')->where('chapter', $value->id)->get();
                            if(isset($clause))
                            {
                                foreach ($clause as $key => $value) {
                                    $templateclause = new TemplateClause();
                                    $templateclause->id = $value->id;
                                    $templateclause->chapter = $value->chapter;
                                    $templateclause->clausetext = $value->clausetext;
                                    $templateclause->variable = $value->variable;
                                    $templateclause->topic = $value->topic;
                                    $templateclause->deleted = $value->deleted;
                                    $templateclause->selectword = $value->selectword;
                                    $templateclause->shortinfo = $value->shortinfo;
                                    $templateclause->sorting = $value->sorting;
                                    $templateclause->created_at = $value->created_at;
                                    $templateclause->updated_at = $value->updated_at;
                                    $templateclause->hidden = $value->hidden;
                                    $templateclause->tstamp = $value->tstamp;
                                    $templateclause->save();
                                    $templateclauses[] = $templateclause;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //DB::commit();
            return response()->success(__('success.showing', ['resource' => 'des Vertrags', 'resourceE' => 'contract']), $templatecontract, 200);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            return response()->error(__('error.showing', ['resource' => 'des Vertrags', 'resourceE' => 'contract']), 400, $e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Yes! A lot... It looks much better now. I have just a small problem with my templatecontract table because it has an extra "user_id" column with no default value so I can't use "create". I think I will add a default value and edit it before save().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So almost all of the `props` from the request matches with the column names. You just need to call the `create` method of [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent) model to create a new record and pass **key value** pair but rather an `object`. Also, you need not to worry about the extra parameters `$contract` contains since `Laravel` will only extract and assign params defined in `protected $fillable` property of the class.

```
// cast object to array
$contract = (array) $contract;
$templateContract = TemplateContract::create($contract)
```

Comment: Thanks man. I don't understand the "create" thing but it works hehe, I will read about it now.